# Enable scrollwheel zooming on a map upon click using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

I am using the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), and wanted to be able to scroll past the map on a mobile device and not have the map zoom when scrolling down a webpage using the scrollwheel.

Here's my code:

```
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.605139, -2.918567),
  zoom: 15,
  scrollwheel: false,
  draggable: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

This is fine but what I would like to achieve is to **enable scrollwheel zooming only when the map was clicked**.

(So on a webpage, when I click the map, I can zoom on it, or a mobile device, when I tap the screen on, then I can pinch and zoom/drag the map around.)

Can I add an event listener to activate draggable only upon double click or single click?
Is it possible using the API?

---

EDIT

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
  var mapOptions = {
    draggable: true,

  };
});
```

Answer (score 29):

This should work:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
          this.setOptions({scrollwheel:true});
        });
```

Comment: thank you for the code snippet I have used it with the code snippet below to make my map work how I wanted +1

Comment: Thx for the good code.It really helps me to give my client quality work!

Comment: Just small update - in my case i want dragging too, so I added same listener for 'drag' event

Comment: for more awesomeness, combine this solution with mrcni's solution. Gotta love SO :)

Answer (score 17):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseout', function(event){
 this.setOptions({scrollwheel:false});  
});
```

this is a handy little consideration in addition to Dr.Molle's answer.

just as it appears, this will re-disable scrollwheel zooming when the mouse leaves the map.

Comment: thank you for this snippet it answered my question in combination with the other snippet provided for the answers to this question.

Comment: This is great for desktops but be aware that then "pinching" to zoom on mobiles does not work.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I generally do:

> User interacts with the map (mousedown) -> set zoomable
>   Mouse rests on the map for over 1 second -> set zoomable
>   Mouse goes out of the map -> set not zoomable

This usually gets the work done. When the user is in the mindset of scrolling the page, the map follows.
When the user wants to zoom in/out they need to interact with it or have the pointer there for a short while.

The source code:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function(event){
    this.setOptions({scrollwheel:true});
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseover', function(event){
    self = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      self.setOptions({scrollwheel:true});
    }, 1000);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseout', function(event){
    this.setOptions({scrollwheel:false});
    clearTimeout(timer);
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution and gathered complete code for disabling scroll on load and enable scroll zoom on click.

Disable scroll on load: scrollwheel: false,
Listen to click event on map and enable scrollwheel: true,

```
map.addListener('click', function() {
    map.set('scrollwheel', true);
});
```

Please find the code in my blog: [http://anasthecoder.blogspot.ae/](http://anasthecoder.blogspot.ae/2015/11/maps-enable-scroll-after-first-click-on.html)

Answer (score 2):

According to official google documentation, to make it work perfectly fine for mobile and website use this:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapid), {
        gestureHandling: 'greedy',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my example and it works for me. When page loads, google map (wheel scroll) is off, when you click on map (wheel scroll) turned on.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-id'), {
            scrollwheel: false,
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseout', function(){
            this.setOptions({scrollwheel:false});
        });
        map.addListener('click', function() {
            map.set('scrollwheel', true);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

this will set map, on click of map if the scrollwheel value is false it will make it true, & if true will make false.

```
function initMap() {

      var florida = {
        lat: 27.5814346,
        lng: -81.0534459
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: florida,
        scrollwheel: false
      });


      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        if (this.scrollwheel == false) {
          this.setOptions({
            scrollwheel: true
          });
        } else {
          this.setOptions({
            scrollwheel: false
          });
        }
      });

    }
```